# Giving default value to vector members and update elements

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm not sure I need a vector for this but I don't think I can use an array because I don't have a fixed size.

I have a Singleton class `Song` which has a member `vector<float> samples;` and a method `getSamples(int numberOfSamples)` When this method is called I want to make the vector the correct size (based on `numberOfSamples`) and than update some of it's values possibly multiple times.

```
vector<float> &Song::getSamples(int numberOfSamples){
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFrames; i++)
        this->samples.push_back(0);
}
```

So for example how do I change the 3rd value to 3 instead of 0? This would be a lot easier with an array, doing something like `samples[2] = 3;` but the problem is that I don't know the length of the vector/array before the getSamples method is called. And I don't think constantly iterating is a good idea because the `numberOfSamples` can be quite big and it's possible I need to update each value up to five times.

Comment: Don't you need a `return` statement?

Comment: Yea I was writing a simplified version of the method and forgot the return statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) the vector, which will value initialise (the default is `T()` which will be `0.0` for `float`) all new values:

```
vector<float> &Song::getSamples(int numberOfSamples){
    this->samples.resize(this->samples.size() + numberOfFrames);
    // did you mean numberOfSamples instead of numberOfFrames, there?
}
```

To set a value for a given index, you can use the subscript operator just like for a plain C-array:

```
this->samples[2] = 3;
```

Comment: I didn't know the C-array notation was possible. Will the resizing also work if the size is basically 0? (when the vector is still empty)

Comment: `vector` value-initializes, not default-initializes. If it did the latter, POD types would remain uninitialized.

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks. Language fail. :)

Comment: @Sled: Sure, you're basically just saying "make room for so many elements". The previous size of the vector is irrelevant (for the user). Note that you could also just use the constructor, if the vector was always empty: `std::vector<float>(numberOfFrames,42.0);`.

Comment: One last question: if the vector already has elements in it and I want to reset it, could I just do `resize(0)` and than resize again to the right size? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Sled: Yes, it will. See the link to cppreference.

Answer (score 0):

How about a lookup table? Something like this:

```
static const float data[5] = { 0.0, 1.5, -8.25, 10.0, Inf };

samples.reserve(samples.size() + numberOfFrames);   // don't forget this!!

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != numberOfFrames; ++i)
{
    samples.push_back(data[i % 5]);
}
```

Otherwise, if most elements are the same, just change the differing ones:

```
samples.resize(samples.size() + numberOfFrames, 25.5f);  // set default to 25.5
for (unsigned int i; i < numberOfSamples; i += 3) { samples[i] = 3.0f; }
```